# Bagging using random forest classifier in sklearn

Tags: random-forest

I built a random forest and I want to find the out of bag score.But my out of bag score is coming out to be 1.0,but it should be less than 1.My sample size consists of 20000 elements.Here is the python code.Please tell the changes to be done.Here X is a numpy array of datasets and Z contains true labels.

```
import csv

import numpy as np

from sklearn import preprocessing

from sklearn import cross_validation

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

with open('C:\Users\Harsh Bhandari\Desktop\letter.csv') as f:

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')

    data = [(col1, int(col2), int(col3), int(col4),int(col5),int(col6),int(col7),int(col8),int(col9),int(col10),int(col11),int(col12),int(col13),int(col14),int(col15),int(col16),int(col17))

                for col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17 in reader]

X=[]

Y=[]

i=0

while i<20000:

        t=data[i][1:]

        X.append(t)

        t=data[i][0]

        Y.append(t)

        i=1+i

X=np.asarray(X)

Y=np.asarray(Y)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

Z=le.fit_transform(Y)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,oob_score=True)

clf=clf.fit(X,Z)

a=clf.predict(X)

scores=clf.score(X,a)

print scores
```

Answer (score 0):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html
In score you send the Test Data and its actual labels, here you are passing the predicted labels itself which match the prediction hence you are 
getting 1.0 score.

Answer (score 0):

i see a couple things here.

you are doing clf.score(X, a)
but you should be doing clf.score(X, Z)
where Z is the true label for X

the score parameter is defined as such clf.score(X, true_labels_for_X)
you instead put the values that you predicted as y_true which dosen't make sense. since Sklearn will already run predict on X, you don't need to pass a.

Also, you can find the oobscore of by doing 
print clf.oob_score_